# No longer able to upload images

Tags: support, bug, uploader

I am having a problem across multiple PCs where I cannot upload images on Stack Overflow any more. I few weeks ago I went to upload an image, but it was to big. Now when I ever go to upload a new one the old image is still uploading, and I cannot cancel it.

This is affecting me across all the stack sites. How can I clear the old upload? I have tried this on my home PC, work PC and work laptop on Chrome and Internet Explorer. The Image wasn't huge, but it was over the limit. Surely, once I couldn't upload, it should have cleared the upload.

Any advice on what I can do?

This is the screen it gets stuck on:

> [image]

Cancel does nothing. Even when I drop a link into it clicking *Upload* does nothing.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Please take a screenshot, you can upload it to imgur.com and put a link here if you can't upload using SE uploader.

Comment: Check your PCs and if they allow it because of the possessive

Comment: @ShadowWizard please see my edit

Comment: Disable your Norton extension for Chrome, or whatever fancy extension of some "anti virus" you installed, they mess with code needed for the upload, and it will work again.

Comment: @shadow wizard. Noice thanks did the job